# Issue with PHP Select SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, select

I have the following php select sql statement, which I can not get it to work. Please help:

```
$sql = "SELECT student_email, student_id, grades_id FROM student_table WHERE email_alert = 1 AND class_grade >= '$var' AND student_id in (
  select student_id
  from student_alerts
  where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < student_grad_date)" ;
```

In this SQL `$var = 85`, `student_id` is a primary key in student_table and a foreign key in the student_alerts table. Also student_id is referenced to the primary key in the student_table. I believe the error might be somewhere around `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the goal of which is to compare if today's date is not past the student's graduation date or it might be something in the syntax that I can not catch.

Thank you!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Is there any error? try to run that code in sql and change the value of var to specific value and see if it do what it does or if an error occurs..

Comment: @SureshKamrushi . From the logs i get "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given", which i know is a sql error.

Comment: @Shadow - Thank you for the tip. I did run the SQL on the DB and it runs successfully. As you suggested the var is the issue. Replacing it with a actual value runs the query. Echo-ing the var gives me the same value, but it doesn't seem to work with or without the parenthesis.

Comment: I'll speculate again.. Try `AND class_grade >= ".$var."`.. If its not working maybe the connection or other factors, also another tip try to learn about [**Prepared Statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and why is it necessary...

Comment: @Shadow. Thank you again. This didn't work, but i am sure that it is something related to escaping characters and something like the parenthesis does not work with AND being directly after.  I have echo-es all over the file for debugging and everything else, including connection executes successfully. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

You are using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which provides a timestamp and student_grad_date is just a date.

You can use CURDATE() instead, which also provide you just the date

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love PHP. After the tips from @Shadow Fiend, i did some research and the correct syntax that worked was:

$sql = "SELECT student_email, student_id, grades_id FROM student_table WHERE email_alert = 1 AND class_grade >= **'". mysql_real_escape_string($var) ."'** AND student_id in (
  select student_id
  from student_alerts
  where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < student_grad_date)" ;